# Disable keyboard focus when a popup displays

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, flutter, keyboard

I am developing a custom view.
I am using this in the Build function to receive key events:

```
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode);
```

and **RawKeyboardListener** widget to detect when user presses a key (space bar).
But when I display a dialog having text fields, the view below catches focus and soft keyboard hides.

How can I either detect there is a dialog popped or detect keyboard key pressed with requesting focus in **Build** function?